# jQuery - Check if element is visible after dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, visible

I'm loading elements via ajax, for a map. Some of them are only visible if you drag (with jquery-ui) the map. (overflow:hidden)
Is there any way I can know if an element(div) is now in the visible part of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the `$(window).height()` and `.width()` and see if the `$('div').position().top` and `.left` are in it.